# How to iterate through a 2D Array with an inner set of non-fixed length?

Tags: arrays, indexing, set, constraints, minizinc

While trying to assign unique values along a 2D array I'm lacking of an idea how to appropriately do this.

I'll have an *2D* `array [1..N_SECTIONS] of var set of int: content` and a set of unique elements `items` that need to be distributed in `content` by a certain rule, in a way that in the end they still don't occur more than once in any of the individual sets of `content`.

I tried to solve this over a nested `forall` however I failed due to I don't see a way to append new elements to the individual sets of an unkown size. Same goes if I would convert this structure to a real 2D array like `array[1..N_SECTIONS,1..N_ITEMS] of int: content` basically because each `section` can have a different amount of members. Additionally this way the array is much oversized since `N_SECTIONS * N_ITEMS >> N_ITEMS (i.e. the unqiue elements to assign)`.

Unfortunately I couldn't find a neat solution to constrain such a distribution in the official docs.

Thanks for any hints in advance!

**Update**:

Here's a dataset (**Note**: the assignment rule here does not guarantee a unique representation of each element, it is just used for demonstration)

```
array[1..5] of int: items = [1,2,3,4,5];
array[1..20] of var set: sections;


constraint forall(cur_sec in 1..3)(
              forall(item in items)(
                 item mod cur_sec == 0 ->
                 sections[cur_sec][card(sections[cur_sec]] = item)); % this is particular line is not working
```

Comment: Would you mind showing the rule that you are using for the distribution of the elements? Even better, a complete (small) example with data would make it easier to understand exactly that you want to achieve.

Comment: the rule isn't too important be it `cur_item mod cur_section == 0 --> array[cur_section, cur_item] = true` - I don't want to overcomplicated at this point. I'm more concerned about managing the set or array of items. Well I have a very large dataset let me see howto streamline it

Comment: There are some syntax errors in your example code which makes it not runnable. What do you mean that it's not working? What would you expect the solution to be?

Comment: I'm looking for a way to assign the individual elements of a set/array with a non-fixed dimension

Comment: You can try to use ` item in ...` instead if `... = item` but this don't work with you existing code since MiniZinc don't allow the construct `sections[cur_sec][card(sections[cur_sec])`. So without more information about the problem I don't know how to help.